# Is there an elegant way to map an alias to its real entity name in a connected data file?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a big csv file containing connected data such as:

```
Source,Target
a,token
b,token2
c,token3
d,j
e,k
f,l
token,g
token2,h
token3,i
```

the structure of the file is mixed, so the rows where the relation is

```
a,token
b,token2
c,token3
```

do not identify specific relations in the network graph, but instead define aliases to which the entities a, b and c are mapped.

In the rest of the file, i have standard relations (d,j; e,k; f,l) but also relations where the real name of the entity is replaced by its alias:

```
token,g
token2,h
token3,i
```

Currently, I am looping over the file with ugly 'for' loops and in such a way I am able to map the relations in the desired way and to get:

```
a,g
b,h
c,i
```

but it's not an elegant way and, perhaps, heavy on my cpu.

Is there any built-in function (maybe in pandas) or some elegant and quick way (few lines of code) to map the file as desidred in Python?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    ['a', 'token'],
    ['b', 'token2'],
    ['c', 'token3'],
    ['d', 'j'],
    ['e', 'k'],
    ['f', 'l'],
    ['token', 'g'],
    ['token2', 'h'],
    ['token3', 'i']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Source', 'Target'])
source_to_target = {row.Source: row.Target for row in df.itertuples()}
df.loc[:, 'AliasedTarget'] = df.loc[:, 'Target'].apply(lambda x: source_to_target.get(x, x))
print(df.head()) 

  Source  Target AliasedTarget
0      a   token          g
1      b  token2          h
2      c  token3          i
3      d       j          j
4      e       k          k
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

1. Fetch the common elements from `source` / `target`.
2. Replace the value of `common elements` in `target` with the required values.
3. Delete the rows with `common elements`.

```
import numpy as np

common_elements = np.intersect1d(df.Source.values, df.Target.values)
df.Target = df.Target.replace(dict(df[df.Source.isin(common_elements)].values))
df = df[~df.Source.isin(common_elements)]
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  Source Target
0      a      g
1      b      h
2      c      i
3      d      j
4      e      k
5      f      l
```

Comment: this is brilliant and works perfectly! thank you. Perhaps, since the columns headers are string and entities (in my case) are integers, I had to convert everything to str:

    common_elements = np.intersect1d(str(df.Source.values), str(df.Target.values))

Comment: the only problem - i realized too late :) is that this deletes valid rows. Being connected data, there are many more common elements (valid edges) than token-entity edges.
for example; if the last row of the df is: "l,a", than it would be deleted.